# Can I simulate mouse movements via terminal without xdotool?

Tags: mouse, screen-lock, xdotool

I would like to write a script to prevent a computer from locking by virtually wiggling the mouse.  However, I do not have `xdotool` on the computer that I am using, and I cannot install since I am not root.  Is there a way to move the cursor without using `xdotool`?

Comment: Why do this instead of just disabling your lock screen?

Comment: Is using `dbus-send` an option to disable the screensaver? [How can I trigger the screensaver's locking feature using D-BUS from the command line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-can-i-trigger-the-screensavers-locking-feature-using-d-bus-from-the-command/107789#107789)

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: http://xkcd.com/196/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That you cannot install `xdotool` because you are not root doesn't mean you cannot run the program, for that you don't need any special privileges.

Just download and compile [from source](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/).

If you don't have access to a compiler then you can download the package for your system directly and extract the file from the package (for `.deb` first use `ar`, extracting from `.rpm` can be done with `rpm2cpio`)

Answer (score 11):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772019/3620917) answer you can move the pointer of your mouse using command-line with the following procedure:

1. First you need to find mouse input device with

   ```
   grep mouse /proc/bus/input/devices | grep event
   ```

You should see something like `H: Handlers=mouse0 event7` in my case. It could output more than one line if you have more than one mouse (e.g. touchpad). The important part is `event7`, it means you will write to `/dev/input/event7`.

2. Then the following will move mouse pointer 100 pixels to the right:

   ```
   seconds=$(date +%s)
   type=2      # EV_REL
   code=0      # REL_X
   value=100   # 100 pixels

   printf '%08X%04X%04X%08X%08X\n' $value $code $type 0 $seconds | xxd -r -p | \
       perl -0777e 'print scalar reverse <>' > /dev/input/event7

   type=0      # EV_SYN
   code=0      # SYN_REPORT
   value=0

   printf '%08X%04X%04X%08X%08X\n' $value $code $type 0 $seconds | xxd -r -p | \
       perl -0777e 'print scalar reverse <>' > /dev/input/event7
   ```

I didn't test whether this procedure is equivalent to real mouse movement in the sense of interrupting locking mechanism.

Comment: This is quite cool. Does someone have a variant for awk without perl?

Comment: Try replacing perl with `rev`